# Image is seen smaller after saved in sdcard

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview

After saving the image my image is appearing small and inside the canvas and also blur and showing black background.Can any one tell me why?

```
        Bitmap mBackground = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth() ,myBitmap.getHeight(),myBitmap.getConfig());

        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBackground);

        //mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBackImage, (mCanvas.getWidth() / 2), 0, null);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap ,mCanvas.getWidth(),mCanvas.getHeight(), null);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap1,x-dx,y-dy, null);

        try
        {
            mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(mBackground);

            Bitmap mNewSaving = mBitmapDrawable .getBitmap();
            String ftoSave = mTempDir + mSaveImageName;
            File mFile = new File(ftoSave);
             Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mFile);

            mNewSaving.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,0, out);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            out.flush();
            out.close();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `mNewSaving.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,0, out);` the second parameter is as follows:

> Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for small size, 100
>   meaning compress for max quality. Some formats, like PNG which is
>   lossless, will ignore the quality setting

So if you want a large image, you should put it `100`

```
mNewSaving.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```

Comment: Thanks it helps me but the height is still smaller than canvas

Comment: What does it mean? How do you verify that height is smaller than canvas?